# Extracting code from Notes Databases as text

Tags: lotusscript, lotus

We all know that it can be a steep learning curve with Lotus Notes / lotusscript etc. There comes a time when a developer (me) realises that one's personal repository for useful code should be accessible across all databases...

Ashamedly, I have several versions of my personal useful subroutines library, spread across all my databases. What I'd like to do is extract all of these AND any subs/functions strewn throughout the databases into a set of files where I can work on putting them all together.

Please, does anyone know how to do this across all databases in a Working Set (does that mean all the DBs in the explorer in Domino Designer?, it should)

I'm happy to process a batch of files containing all my source code, provided I have the name of the code block and the DB it came from. I've been struggling to get such a thing from design synopsis or search in eclipse.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could right-click on each database and select Application > Design Synopsis.
Then you select Agents and Script Libraries, and if you have a lot of code directly in forms you may want to select Forms as well. This will generate a Design Synopsis with (probably) most of your code.

If you don't want to do this for each database, you could write a script that will export the design elements you want as DXL, and you can then parse out the code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many databases you have, Source Control could be an option.

You can use source control to sync your design to a git repository.  If you remove the preference for "Binary DXL" you will get all of your code in plain text in a folder structure.  You can then use external tools to parse out your subs and functions.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little utility for myself that traverses the tree of NSF files on a server and exports all design elements to DXL. I'm not looking at it at the moment, but as I recall, it can do some pattern-matching to narrow down the set of NSF files that it processes. Like a lot of the tools I've written for myself, it's a database with a form and a button, and it creates one output document per design element, showing them in an view that gives the NSF filename, design element name and type.

Somebody who is properly motivated could conceivably modify this code to zero in only on design elements containing script, parse the script portions of the DXL into individual subs and functions, and produce output files instead of (or in addition to) creating the output documents.